# Trying to compare data and increment a counter. VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of data and I am trying to compare each cell in that column to another column to see if they match. If they do I want another cell to count up for each instance the data matches.
Below is the code I have tried so far.

[Example of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoM1e.png)

```
Do While i <= 60
    j = 0
    Do While j <= 20
        If [A" & i & "] = [I" & j & "] Then Range("B" & i & "").Value = Range("B" & i & "").Value + 1
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: `[A1]` nomenclature cannot be used with variables.  You will need to use `Range()`: `ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)`

Comment: Also `j` and `i` will need to start at `1` and not `0` as there is no row `0`

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you for your help this solved my question.